# Как получить путь к исполняемому файлу?

Tags: c#, файлы, файловая-система, c#-7.0, файловые-пути

Какой код (на C#) нужно написать, чтобы после его публикации он мог вывести на консоль путь к файлу .exe, который я запускаю?
Я попробовал использовать метод `GetFullPath(string path)` класса `Path`:

- При запуске до публикации он возвращает `C:...\bin\Release\CurFile.exe` - то есть как я и задумывал
- После публикации (например на рабочий стол) он возвращает примерно такое: `C:...\Local\Apps\2.0\4ALJB3ND.EZ5\V2O37DW3.KY1\CurF..tion_709be53d74e244ac_0001.0000_bcdca66edd3abf8b\CurFile.exe` - это мне уже не подходит

Я попробовал другие методы - аналогичный результат. Может кто знает как решить такую проблему?

P.s. Я работаю в Visual Studio, и публикацию делаю через ClickOnce

Comment: *"это мне уже не подходит"* - однако это же путь к файлу .exe, который вы запустили

Comment: Это правда, он возвращает путь к файлу .exe, который я запустил. Возможно я некорректно описал проблему. Я хочу, чтобы программа вывела в консоль именно место запуска программы. Честно не знаю как объяснить.
Запустил программу а Рабочем столе, она должна вывести путь с Рабочим столом

Comment: Если подразумевается "Запустил программу ярлыком на рабочем столе", то никак. Можно только узнать текущую директорию (которая прописана в ярлыке и может не совпадать с рабочим столом) https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.getcurrentdirectory?view=net-8.0

Comment: Cwd чтоль нужен?

Comment: Так оно вам правильно всё возвращает. Можете попробовать `Environment.CurrentDirectory` глянуть. Она прописывается в ярлыке как рабочий каталог.